# How to optimize this 2-Dimensional DP (Dynamic Program) solution to 1-D?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The following page contains a 2-D DP solution to the "subset sum" problem:

https://github.com/mission-peace/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/dynamic/SubsetSum.java

Core method:

```
boolean[][] T = new boolean[input.length + 1][total + 1];
for (int i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
    T[i][0] = true;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= total; j++) {
        if (j - input[i - 1] >= 0) {
            T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j] || T[i - 1][j - input[i - 1]];
        } else {
            T[i][j] = T[i-1][j];
        }
    }
}
return T[input.length][total];
```

I'm trying to reduce the space usage by replacing the 2-D array w/ a 1-D one like this:

```
boolean[] T = new boolean[sum + 1];     
T[0] = true;      

for (int i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
        if (j - input[i - 1] >= 0) {
            T[j] = T[j] | T[j - input[i - 1]]; //not using ||
        } 
    }
}
return T[sum];
```

and I failed miserably: it's returning true for any inputs. Can someone point out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Topological ordering of your solution is incorrect.

If you change the second loop to `for (int j = sum; j >= 1; j--)` it should work.

It happens because when you move forward in the second loop, you are also considering solutions that were solved by the `current index i` and therefore including the current element multiple times in the solution instead of only including it once.